# Local existence of flat metrics with degenerate singular values

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It has been [proved](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Sur-l%E2%80%99existence-locale-de-certaines-metriques-Gasqui/28e72863cb2fdaebe98288cce8427bc368229bfd) that,

If $\lambda_1,\,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n$ are real analytic functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, such that $\lambda_i(0)\neq \lambda_j(0)$ for $i\neq j$, then there exists a (real, analytic-) orthonormal coframe $\left(\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_n\right)$ in $(\mathbb{R}^n,g_0)$, with $g_0$ the standard Euclidean metric, defined in a neighbordhood of the origin such that the Riemannian metric

$$
g=\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{\lambda_i}\omega_i^2
$$

is flat. The condition $\lambda_i(0)\neq \lambda_j(0)$ overwhelms several physical applications, and I wonder if one can prove the same (or a similar) result when two of the functions, say $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, are identical, or at least when all the $\lambda$'s are constant and two of them are equal. The case $n=3$ is particularly interesting, but a naïve calculation of the Ricci tensor of the metric

$$
g=e^{\lambda_1}\left(\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d} z-\cos\theta\,\left(\cos\phi\,\mathrm{d} x+\sin\phi\,\mathrm{d} y\right)\right)^{2}+e^{\lambda_1}\left(\sin\phi\,\mathrm{d} x-\cos\phi\,\mathrm{d} y\right)^{2}+e^{\lambda_3}\left(\cos\theta\,\mathrm{d} z+\sin\theta\,\left(\cos\phi\,\mathrm{d} x+\sin\phi\,\mathrm{d} y\right)\right)^{2}
$$

($\lambda_1\neq\lambda_3$ constanst) explodes, and it's not evident that one can find functions $\theta$ and $\phi$ that render the metric flat.

Comment: When all the $\lambda$s are constant, then any "constant" coframe will give you a flat metric.

Comment: @WillieWong True. How about if we add the requirement of "non-constant" frame. Is there any evident obstruction ?

Comment: When all the $\lambda$s are constant and two of them are equal (as you wrote), you can also give a non-constant frame by rotating among the equal eigenvalues. For example, suppose you have $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 \neq \lambda_3$, set $e_i$ the standard coframe and $\omega_1 = \cos(x_3) e_1 + \sin(x_3) e_2$ and $\omega_2 = \sin(x_3) e_1 - \cos(x_3) e_2$ and $\omega_3 = e_3$, then you have a "non-constant" solution. // Rather than trying to impose arbitrary meaningless restrictions, you should just accept that the constant $\lambda$ case is trivial and focus on the case where $\lambda$s vary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classifying the solutions is a non-trivial problem when two of the $\lambda_i$ are equal, even when they are constants.  The reason is that this is essentially an overdetermined problem when two of the $\lambda_i$ are equal.

The point is this:  When the $\lambda_i$ are distinct, a choice of an orthonormal coframing $\omega = (\omega_i)$ is essentially a map of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, i.e., a choice of three functions of 3 variables.  The requirement that the metric $g$ as defined above be flat is three equations, i.e., the vanishing of the three symmetric functions of the eigenvalues of the Ricci tensor of $g$.  It's not surprising that this system of equations has local solutions (when the $\lambda_i$ are distinct and real-analytic).  Setting it up as an exterior differential system, one quickly finds that this system is involutive, and the Cartan-Kähler theorem does the job.  (N.B.:  This fact is not special to $3$-dimensions or to flatness.  The Cartan-Kähler analysis I describe in [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383244/local-obstructions-for-maps-with-constant-singular-values/383251#383251) generalizes without significant change to cover the case of not-necessarily-constant prescribed real-analytic singular value functions $\lambda_1<\lambda_2<\cdots<\lambda_n$ on $M$ for real-analytic local mappings $f:(M^n,g)\to (N^n, h)$ between any two real-analytic Riemannian manifolds.)

However, when $\lambda_1=\lambda_2\not=\lambda_3$, the situation is entirely different.  Now, one doesn't need to specify a complete orthonormal coframe, just $\omega_3$, a unit $1$-form, which is essentially a map of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $S^2$, i.e., two functions of $3$ variables.  Now, if $g_0$ is the Euclidean metric, we can write $g$ in the form
$$
g = e^{\lambda_1} g_0 + (e^{\lambda_3}-e^{\lambda_1})\,{\omega_3}^2,
$$
and the flatness condition on $g$, i.e., $\mathrm{Ric}(g) = 0$ is still three equations on the two unknowns that go into the definition of $\omega_3$.  For generic $\lambda_1\not=\lambda_3$, one does not expect there to be *any* solutions, even locally, but constructing an actual example of a pair $(\lambda_1,\lambda_3)$ for which no solution exists might be hard.  (As a comparison, consider the even more restrictive case in which all the $\lambda_i$ are equal.  There, one definitely gets conditions on the function $\lambda = \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3$ in order for $e^\lambda g_0$ to be flat.  In fact, there is only a 4-parameter family of (local) functions $\lambda$ that satisfy these conditons, and, of course, we know these explicitly.)  I expect that there will be *some* set of PDE relating $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_3$ whose satisfaction tells whether solutions exist, but I have a feeling that this compatibility condition is liable to be quite complicated.

Even when $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_3$ are constants, classifying the solutions is not trivial.  Clearly, one can reduce to the case in which $\lambda_1=0$ by scaling $g$ by a constant (which won't affect its flatness).  For simplicity, set $e^{\lambda_3} = a^2\not=1$.  As Willie Wong has observed, taking $\omega_3$ to have constant coefficients always gives a solution, which one can regard as 'trivial'.

Meanwhile, there are nontrivial solutions:  Consider the following construction:  Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an interval and let $f = (f_i):I\to S^2$ be a smooth mapping.  Consider, the $1$-parameter family of metrics
$$h_{f,b}= du^2 + dv^2 + b^2\,\bigl(f_1(t)\,u + f_2(t)\,v + f_3(t)\bigr)^2\,dt^2$$
in the domain $D_f\subset\mathbb{R}^2\times I$ where $h_{f,b}$ is positive definite, i.e., the complement of the locus where $f_1(t)\,u + f_2(t)\,v + f_3(t)=0$.  Here $b>0$ is a constant parameter.  It is simple to verify that $h_{f,b}$ is a flat metric for any choice of $f$ and $b$.  As a result, there is a smooth local isometry $\phi_f:D_f\to\mathbb{R}^3$ so that $\phi_f^*(g_0) = h_{f,1}$, where $g_0$ is the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Restricting the domain of $\phi_f$ to some open subset $D'_f\subset D_f$, if necessary, one can arrange that $\phi_f:D'_f\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be injective.  Hence there will exist a unique quadratic form
$g_{\lambda_3}$ on the (open) image $\phi_f(D'_f)\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\phi_f^*(g_{\lambda_3}) = h_{f,a}$.  By construction,
$$
g_{\lambda_3} = g_0 + (e^{\lambda_3}-1)\,{\omega_3}^2,
$$
where $\omega_3$ is a $1$-form (of unit size with respect to $g_0$); in fact,
$$
\phi_f^*(\omega_3) = \bigl(f_1(t)\,u + f_2(t)\,v + f_3(t)\bigr)\,dt.
$$
It's easy to show that this $g_{\lambda_3}$ is a 'trivial' solution if and only if $f_1 = f_2 = 0$, i.e., $f:I\to S^2$ is the constant map to either the north or south pole.

Thus, this construction gives a class of local solutions that essentially depend on two functions of one variable.

The remaining question is whether there are any solutions that are *not* equivalent to one of these up to isometries in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

What one can say is that, if there are any such solutions for given constants $\lambda_1 = 0$ and $\lambda_3\not=0$, there are not very many, even locally.
More precisely, using the Cartan structure equations, one can show the following:  Suppose that one has a unit $1$-form $\omega_3$, such that
$$
g =  g_0 + (e^{\lambda_3}-1)\,{\omega_3}^2
$$
is flat (where $\lambda_3$ is a nonzero constant).   Let $X$ be the vector field $g_0$-dual to $\omega_3$ and consider the quadratic form
$$
Q = \mathscr{L}_X\bigl(g_0-{\omega_3}^2\bigr).
$$
If $Q$ is identically zero, then $g$ arises locally from the above construction using an $f:I\to S^2$.  Moreover, there is at most a $6$-dimensional space of local solutions $\omega_3$ that have a non-zero $Q$.  (Probably, the space of such solutions has considerably smaller dimension, but I don't know how much smaller.)